Is there any possible way to send Udp requests faster in SharpPcap (.NET 8)?
I'm unable to achieve a delay between requests of less than 50 microseconds (10 microseconds is required). No optimizations, such as running on multiple warmed-up threads, seem to help (apparently, there's some kind of lock under the hood). The requests are sent via an Ethernet cable. Are there any other settings or approaches that could help reduce the delay?
    _device.OnPacketArrival += ProcessPacketArrival;
    _device.Open(DeviceModes.MaxResponsiveness | DeviceModes.NoCaptureLocal, -1);
    _device.NonBlockingMode = true;
    _device.StartCapture();

    //delay between requests 50+ microseconds
    _device.SendPacket(_cachedBytes.AsSpan());
    _device.SendPacket(_cachedBytes.AsSpan());

Tried: various configurations, multithreading and etc.
Expect: delay between requests not more than 10 microseconds.
Solved: In my case, the solution was to use the SendQueue class from SharpPcap. Setting the size in the constructor and adding messages via SendQueue.Add with the required number of packets, you can then call _sendQueue.Transmit. In my scenario, the timeout between requests is about 5 microseconds, and between Transmits, it's 24 milliseconds.

What is the bitrate of your network and what the UDP packet length? Within 10 microseconds, your packets have to be written and then read. The speed also depends on the IP version (IPv4 or IPv6). For IPv4, at least 20 IP bytes and 8 UDP bytes have to be transmitted per UDP packet. Sending such a 224-bit packet with 100 MBit/s takes at least 2.2 uSec. Reading it, another 2.2 uSec. Computing and validating the checksum. Overhead of the network card, etc. So, 10 uSec does sound challenging if your are using a high-level language like c# on a non-realtime operating system.

Thank you for your answer. The speed is 100 mbps. IP version is IPv4. The size of Udp packet is 43 bytes (only 1 byte for data). Computing and validation the checksum are disabled in my case (they're hardcoded). I've tested the standard UdpClient in C# and it gives me 20 usec. Checksum offload are disabled on the network adapter (for ipv4 and udp). Seems like I have to use other language for that task, but first I would like to try to use C# as much as possible. If there's nothing that can be done, then I'll have to

Nice answer.  Do you  think you could put it in an actual answer box, and include some sample code?

@RobertHarvey, done

In my case, the solution was to use the SendQueue class from SharpPcap.
Sample:
_device.OnPacketArrival += ProcessPacketArrival;
_device.Open(DeviceModes.MaxResponsiveness | DeviceModes.NoCaptureLocal, -1);
_device.NonBlockingMode = true;
_device.StartCapture();

const int QueueSize = 4096;
using SendQueue sendQueue = new SendQueue(QueueSize);


//This is how to add with no delay
sendQueue.Add(ethernetPacket1.Bytes);
sendQueue.Add(ethernetPacket2.Bytes);

//if you want to control the delays between requests, add offset
//This is how to add with custom delay
int usecOffset = 0;
int secOffset = 0;

usecOffset += DelayBetweenRequestsUsec;
secOffset += DelayBetweenRequestsSec;
sendQueue.Add(ethernetPacket3.Bytes, secOffset, usecOffset);

usecOffset += DelayBetweenRequestsUsec;
secOffset += DelayBetweenRequestsSec;
sendQueue.Add(ethernetPacket4.Bytes, secOffset, usecOffset);

sendQueue.Transmit(_device, true);

Make sure the size of SendQueue is sufficient (remember additional bytes for timeval for every packet depends on your OS Marshal.SizeOf<timeval_windows/timeval_macosx/timeval_unix>()). The Add method of SendQueue will return false, if it is not enough.
This code is just an example.
